# Bind a related entities to a data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, viewmodel

I am using Entity Framework 6.1. In my model, two entities **Country** and **Districts**. as:

```
public class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        Districts = new HashSet<District>();
    }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryArabicName { get; set; }
    public string CountryEnglishName { get; set; }
    public string NationalityArabicName { get; set; }
    public string NationalityEnglishName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; private set; }
}

public class District
{
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string DistrictArabicName { get; set; }
    public string DistrictEnglishName { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

So, Country has many Provinces.

In my ViewModel:

```
private IEnumerable<District> _districts;
public IEnumerable<District> Districts
{
    get { return _districts; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _districts, value); }
}
```

Then, fill it:

```
Districts =  (from district in cmsDbContext.Districts
                orderby district.DistrictId
                select district).ToList();
```

In the View:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:DistrictVm/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<DataGrid Height="308" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Districts}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DistrictArabicName}" Header="District" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Country.CountryArabicName}" Header="Country" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Now, **DistrictArabicName** is shown correctly. But nothing for **Country.CountryArabicName**

What shall I do to solve this?. I want to retrieve **Country.CountryArabicName**

Comment: CountryArabicName  is a property of Country class, do you have the country object in your viewmodel (i.e. in DistrictVm) ? or do you have other viewmodel for country objects?

Comment: @Kylo Ren. I don't have **Country** object in **DistrictVm**. But, I do have **CountryVm**. What is the relation between them, I didn't get it!. At first, I thought that I can get **Country** from **District**.

Comment: Your Binding was correct, but as you said it was not working meaning the Country property of  District class is either null or the  CountryArabicName  property is null/not set. Make sure those properties has values. I suggested country object hoping that somehwere in ViewModel you may have a country collection which can be bound to you column binding using relative source binding. You need to debug this out what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @Kylo Ren. Correct!. They are null. I changed **public Country Country { get; set; }** to **public virtual Country Country { get; set; }**, just added **virtual**, and now not null, but I got "erw" instead of real data.

Comment: I can't think how defining the property as virtual can help.But my questions are. 1. when cmsDbContext.Districts collection is filled do you fill the country property value also. 2. if 1 is no, then where have you defined the CountryVm, in which view, can't you access the country value from there?

Comment: @Kylo Ren. No, the collection has no data except for **CountryId* which is the foreign key. Just "erw" word instead of other fields. **CountryVm** is another in another view. I don't know how can I use it in **DistrictVm**.

Comment: may be filling the country values in district collection is easy approach then accessing the whole other viewmodel. wherever you are filling this district collection fill country values with them, UI logic is correct on that basis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kylo Ren.

What I did to solve the problem:
- Remove virtual to disable lazy loading. The data is too small. less than 20 records.
- Delete all migrations and the database.
- Re-enable migration again, and update the database.

Now, my example is working.